# Why are my header and paragraph on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I've been searching for hours and can't find answers that I've been able to make work for my case.

I'm trying to make a simple (one line header, one line paragraph) page for a personal-use wordpress plugin I'm writing, with all text centered both vertically and horizontally, but the header and paragraph always display on the same line, like this:

---

**Server Is Down**The game server is currently down. Please check back later.

---

Here's the full code of the page:

```
<?php $sitename = get_bloginfo('name'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $sitename; ?> - Game Server Is Down</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .centered {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="centered">
      <h1>Server Is Down</h1>
      <p>The game server is currently down. Please check back later.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You have it inside a flexbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of **Flex** is making both elements go on the same line, because the default *flex-direction* is `row`.

Use

```
  flex-direction: column;
```

Example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.centered {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <h1>Server Is Down</h1>
  <p>The game server is currently down. Please check back later.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I figured it was something simple like this I was missing.

Thanks for helping out a gradually-learning amateur!

Comment: Depending on your design, you might not even need flexbox. Good luck with the rest of your work :)

Comment: Done! Tried to do it sooner, but it made me wait 10 minutes before I could accept it.